# UITableView into a UIScrollView?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I'm looking to have two views which are part of a constituent set. Data in each view would be best represented in a UITableView. I'd like to then add a gesture to flicker the view off screen and have another similar view brought in, with a page indicator control. My fear is that UITableView intercepts touches and becomes the responder to any such 'flickering' which the UIView might be waiting for. This will directly impede on the usability of the application.

So my question to you usability/UI experts is, is putting a UITableView inside of UIPageControl a poor design choice?

Answer (score 3):

A UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView. The PageControl sample provided with the iPhone SDK explains nicely how to use a UIScrollView with UIPageControl. Any method which belongs to UIScrollViewDelegate will be called inside your view controller if the view controller implements UITableViewDelegate.

To achieve what you are trying to do, the best approach would be to use UITableView with UIPageControl as explained in the PageControl sample.

Hope that helps!